# qrcode wont work inside a caption

Tags: floats, qrcode

i'd like to use a `\qrcode` inside of a `\caption`, like:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex 
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{polyglossia}\setdefaultlanguage{german} 
\usepackage{graphicx, qrcode} 
 
\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}
%\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{02-794.jpg}
\caption{\qrcode{https://www.scinexx.de/fotos/schiffsspuren-in-den-wolken/} }
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

but `\qrcode` seems only to work outside of a `\caption`… The code above produces the error:

```
! Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.12 ...exx.de/fotos/schiffsspuren-in-den-wolken/} }
```

what is the meaning of this error? How can i solve this?

Comment: Untested `\protect\qrcode`

Comment: Do you want that QR code to also show up in the list of figures? If not, `\caption[<caption-for-list-of-figures>]{<caption-with-qr-code>}` should do the job.

Comment: I confirm `\protect\qrcode` works. Be sure to remove the `.aux` file before running again LuaLaTeX after adding `\protect` (this removal isjust once).

Comment: thank you very much! I also confirm, that `\protect` does the trick – but only for rather simple input: 

`\listoffigures     \begin{figure}  \caption{\protect\qrcode{https} }  \end{figure}`

works fine (even with an qr-code in the listoffigures), but not with `\qrcode{https://www.scinexx.de/fotos/schiffsspuren-in-den-wolken/}` – then the following error occurs: 

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
\datablock@2 
l.10 ...exx.de/fotos/schiffsspuren-in-den-wolken/} }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you daleif, Skillmon and egreg. While your `\protect` is a solution for qr-codes, which link to maximum-two-character-links like: `\caption{\protect\qrcode{https://ab.com}}` is doesn't work for more-than-two-character-links…

A workaround for those situations could be:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{qrcode}
\begin{document}
\qrcode{https://tex.stackexchange.com}
\end{document}
```

combined with an:

```
\caption{\includegraphics{standalone_qrcode.pdf}}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments,  you need to `\protect` the qrcode, so that LaTeX doesn't try to write the expansion of the macro `\qrcode` to the aux file.

But this leads one to wonder why LaTeX is writing the caption to the aux file.  And the answer to that is in case you have a `\listoffigures`, so that TeX can repeat the caption there.  But if the qrcode is related to the image it's captioning, then it would be strange to have the qrcode in the list of figures without the image that it's captioning.

LaTeX offers a solution: the `\caption` command has an optional argument for the content that should appear in the list of figures (also mentioned in the comments).  This is more often used for long captions, so that you have `\caption[short caption that should appear in the list of figures which doesn't have enough space for the full text of the longer caption that appears in the text]{long caption}`.  (Probably that should be `\caption[short caption]{long caption that takes too much space for the list of figures}`.)  We can use this idea to have a version of the caption without the qrcode in the list of figures and a version of the caption in the main text.  And it turns out that the caption in the main text doesn't need to be `\protect`ed.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qrcode} 

\begin{document} 

\listoffigures

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
\caption{My caption says \protect\qrcode{https://tex.stackexchange.com}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption[My caption says qrcode]{My caption says \qrcode{https://tex.stackexchange.com}}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```